# How to debug custom cocoa pod library?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, cocoapods

I have created a pod using `pod lib create MyPod` also enabled to include Example project. Created a class Ping under `Classes` folder. Made `PodSpec` points to the local source path. After doing `pod install` and `import MyPod` code completion shows Ping is available. However, code is crashing with `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` when creating an instance of Ping.

It breaks at the code in Example project, where I am instantiating. The break point in the init of Ping not working or even an attempt to step-in from Example project.

I followed this [blog](https://medium.com/@shahabejaz/create-and-distribute-private-libraries-with-cocoapods-5b6507b57a03). This and many other blogs shows happy path and no details on debugging pod lib code.

Any pointers to help me on this would be great. Thanks.

Here is my code and call stack. And the crash occurs only when we invoke a member, not when instantiating.

[image: crash screenshot]

This is all I got in Ping class under development pod.

```
@objcMembers
public class Ping {

    public init() {}

    public var greetings: String {
        get {
            return "Hello"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You'll likely need to share a pointer to your code since those steps should work and probably something was missed.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien, update my question with more details.

Comment: Without changing anything above screenshot demo project started working. But, my actual project still having this problem. I will compare between the two to figure out and post the update here.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien, I found resolution and posted the answer. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: You can debug. just make 1 changes in your file which you want to debug - unlock the file.

Q - How to unlock - 
A: Just make changes in your profile like add print line etc.

Answer (score -1):

Actually a thoughtless **Clean build folder** from **product menu (with Opt key pressed)** fixed this issue.

For every modification I do to the pod lib code, it caused same issue and 'Clean build folder' solving it.